# Integrating video upload in Laravel 5.1 using Vimeo servers

Tags: laravel, video, laravel-5, vimeo, vimeo-api

I am building a web application using Laravel 5.1. So far I have enabled users to upload up to 9 photos. Now I want to enable them to upload videos. Since I don't have the resources to handle many video files, I want to use vimeo's servers. I submitted my app for approval and this is what I got.

> Approved for the following accounts: Basic accounts PLUS accounts PRO
>   accounts

So far so good. What I don't understand is can I upload video to vimeo without storing it to server in Laravel? I mean I know I can, I just want to do it directly. User sees a form. Uploads a video, it goes to their servers and then I use their api to show the video in my web application. Is that possible or do I have to pay for that? And one more thing, can you suggest me good packages?

Comment: Have you tried "Simple HTTP Post Uploading" described at https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos ?  It tells you exactly how to do it?

Comment: Yeah, https://github.com/vinkla/vimeo - this is the package I'm using. I am getting "Unable to locate file to upload" error. Vimeo::upload($request->file('video')->getRealPath(), false); - this the code from my controller